# ajax link being hidden when clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I am attempting to use ajax to load a form into my page which is partly working.
The issue i seem to be having is that when the link is clicked the content loads, but the the links disappears, also when the content is loaded, none of the javascript within that content area works

**Sidebar with links**

```
- content_for :sidenav do
  - @pages.each do |obj|
    %li= link_to(obj.name, edit_admin_page_path(obj), :remote => true)
```

**Ajax to render partial**

```
$('#page_view').html('<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'edit') %>')
```

**Partial to be render**

```
= simple_form_for(@page, :url => admin_page_path(@page), :method => :put, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |form|
  = render form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Content**

You mention your links / content will disappear after the Ajax update

The problem will be to do with this line:

```
$('#page_view').html('<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'edit') %>')
```

Your links will fall within the `#page_view` element, meaning when you update its HTML, you remove the links / other content too. To fix this, you need to issue the `.html` command on the specific container you need

---

**Links**

Your links won't work because Javascript can't bind to elements not present on DOM load

You'll typically have something like this:

```
$(".element").on("event", function() {
    //Your stuff here
});
```

The problem here is because `.element` won't exist in your document before your Ajax call, it won't be bound, and consequently prevent your events from triggering actions. To get around this, you need to [delegate](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp) from an element which will be present at DOM load, like this:

```
$(document).on("event", ".element", function() { 
    //Your Code
});
```

Comment: cheers @rich, within the form I'm rendering I am using Foundations tabs, would this DOM issue still be present with this?

Comment: Hmm I've not used the Foundations stuff before - have you got a link?

Comment: This looks like a type of JS element! My code is still valid :) You'll have DIV elements which you're replacing etc. These elements need to be bound with JS, which can only happen with delegation